# IntelliJ Not using local repo for maven builds

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am trying to build my spring boot (maven) project locally, but the build fails because IntelliJ is looking for a company specific artifact in the main maven repo :https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2

ERROR

````
Failure to find [company artifact] in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be re```attempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
````

I have set my maven settings to point to my local repo
[image]

How do I get my maven projects to build using only local artifacts?

POM.XML

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>gov.utah.deg</groupId>
    <artifactId>woodburnhb357</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.${build}</version>
    <name>woodburnhb357</name>
    <description>Woodburn HB357</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

        <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Data migration into Oracle -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--Database -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <version>12.2.0.1</version>
            <!--needed for local build to be successful -->
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/lib/ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <!--Qualtrics Download -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--Logging-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>gov.utah.dts.eng.auth</groupId>
            <artifactId>dts-spring-auth-helpers</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>gov.utah.dts.eng.oidc</groupId>
            <artifactId>lib-oidc</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-openid</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.cache</groupId>
            <artifactId>cache-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--End security dependencies-->

        <!--Testing-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.1</version>
                <!--<configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>-->
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <workingDirectory>react</workingDirectory>
                    <installDirectory>target</installDirectory>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install node and npm</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <nodeVersion>v10.19.0</nodeVersion>
                            <npmVersion>6.4.0</npmVersion>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm install</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>install</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm run build</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>run build</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <copy todir="${project.build.directory}/classes/public">
                                    <fileset dir="${project.basedir}/react/build"/>
                                </copy>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Can we see your pom?

Comment: @ghosh - just added

Comment: What I don't understand: `How do I get my maven projects to build using only local artifacts?`? Have you run a full working build already ? Are you in a corporate environment?

Comment: I can build successfully through our CI/CD pipeline but i need to be able to test/troubleshoot specific issues that require local clean/compile/test/install. I currently am unable to do that

Answer (score 0):

1. case: If you company artifact comes from a company repository that you reference in your ´settings.xml`or`pom.xml`, you can just delete the directory in`.m2/repository`that belongs to that artifact and try again (directories are of the form`com/something/artifactId/version`).
2. case: If the company artifact was directly installed into the local repository, you need more fine-grained surgery. Go the directory in the local repository where you suspect the artifact. Then remove all files that end with `.lastupdated` and then try again.

Comment: why would I delete the artificat(s) from my local directory? How does that solution stop maven from looking at /repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 directy?

Comment: The problem is not that Maven looks into that repository. The problem is that Maven does not find the desired artifact in any of the repositories and also not in the local repository. Maven always looks into all repositories and the local one before it fails. So probably there is something wrong in your local repository.